# Implement abstract method with return type of self

Tags: scala, generics

I am working on a web app where I have a bunch of models.

Every model extends and implements the following abstract class:

```
abstract class BaseModel {
    val dateCreated: String
    val dateUpdated: String
}

trait BaseModelCompanion[A <: BaseModel] {
    implicit val reads: Reads[A]
    implicit val writes: Writes[A]
}
```

Example:

```
case class User(id: String, name: String, dateCreated: String, dateUpdated: String) extends BaseModel {
    ...
}

object User extends BaseModelCompanion[User] {
    implicit val reads = Reads[User] = (...)
    implicit val writes = new Writes[User] { ... }
}
```

---

Now I want to add an abstract method to my BaseModel called `update`, where each model will take in some Json and return a clone of itself.  This is what an implementation would look like:

```
case class User(id: String, dateCreated: String, dateUpdated: String) extends BaseModel {

    // Every model needs one of these
    def update(jsValue: JsValue): User = {
        copy(
            name = (jsValue \ "name").as[String].get,
            ...
        )
    }
}
```

My problem is that I am struggling to define the abstract method signature:

```
abstract class BaseModel {
    val dateCreated: String
    val dateUpdated: String

    def update(jsValue: JsValue): ______  // How do I say return an object of type "self"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use F-bounded polymorphism

```
abstract class BaseModel[A <: BaseModel[A]] {
    val dateCreated: String
    val dateUpdated: String

    def update(jsValue: String): A
}

case class User(id: String, dateCreated: String, dateUpdated: String) extends BaseModel[User] {
    def update(jsValue: String): User = {
        copy(id = jsValue)
    }
}
```

**EDIT by `oxbow_lakes`**

The feature you are hoping for has been called *mytype* and has been suggested in the past as trivially implementable by `scalac` as an additional language feature (by *@extempore*). IIRC it was rejected at the time because of some obscure corner cases. (See the distant history of the scala mailing lists)